# Combining text files like how 'include' in PHP works using python

Tags: python

I would like to combine some text files like how `include` works in PHP.

A piece of code is fine but some existing solution or package that does the job  would be preferred.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish in detail.

For example,
`main.html`

```
<html>
<body>
   <header>
   <<<INCLUDE header.html>>>
   </header>
   Content 
   <footer>
   <<<INCLUD footer.html>>>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

`header.html` and `footer.html` contain some partial HTML.

and I after running python script, I would like to have a NEW file called `processed.html` generated with all those 3 files combined.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it just python? Or, you are using any web frameworks like Django or Flask?

Comment: Any solutions but gotta be able to be automated in Linux environment. I don't know how Django or Flask exactly work but I know some JavaScript solution is not what I am looking for. Thank you :) @AKS

Comment: I believe the jinja template engine can standalone from Flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
html = open("main.html").read()
for match in re.findall('\<<<INCLUDE.*?\>>>',s):
    name = match.replace("<<<INCLUDE ","").replace(">>>","")
    content = open(name).read()
    html = html.replace(match,content)

open("processed.html","w").write(html)
```

Comment: It would be very nice if I could automate the scanning of INCLUDEs in target html file. The example only contained header and footer but other files have different and more INCLUDEs. If I don't get any other answers, I will try to improve your code and use it. :) Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! I will modify the code to get the input file path and the output file path from arguments and use it. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/letsdevus/62f03d28d11151275a0878b37dd71886 My Full Implementation here. :) Just put the script in the same folder and change the ext of HTML files that contain INCLUDEs to .mhtml. Then run the script. It will detect *.mhtml and produce *.html.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a [Templating Engines](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating).

For example, in [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#template-inheritance), you may do something like:

```
<html>
<body>
   <header>
   {% include 'header.html' %}
   </header>
   Content 
   <footer>
   {% include 'footer.html' %}
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Btw, can Jinja produce an output file?

Comment: According to [http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Template.render] `template.render()` will return the rendered template as unicode string, so you should be able to store that to any file you want.

Comment: Thank you! I've checked out Jinja website. Installation seemed a bit tedious (for my current environment). It would be very nice if it supported NPM or Bower.